# How introduce sound wave in molecular dynamics or dissipative dynamic particles?

Tags: acoustics, dissipation, molecular-dynamics

How could I introduce sound wave in molecular dynamics or dissipative dynamic particles?
 What do specify which is applicable between molecular dynamics and dissipative particle dynamics? problem is simulating a 50 nm bubble in a MHz sound waves.

Comment: What kind of sound wave might you mean (constant frequency or what)? What is the ensemble you are using (and boundary conditions)? You'll get a wave of sorts by introducing density differences.

Comment: Please put some more details into your question - one large issue is the time step for your caclulations and the total time period and how this compares to the frequency/*period* of the sound waves.

Comment: I want to simulate collapse of a bubble by means of a constant MHz wave. N and T are constant.

Answer (score 1):

DPD doesn't have attractive forces so I don't see how it's possible to simulate a bubble with it. And a 50 nm bubble with MD? I hope you have a *lot* of computing power!

Assuming you use MD: I think the most elegant solution would be to use NVT with periodic boundary conditions, and modify the MD code you're using so that the cell vectors in one of the directions are sinusoidally varied at the desired frequency.